# Assign values to a key in a dictionary python

Tags: python

Since I wanted to append a new ID to a dictionary key, I created a new dictionary, based on the old dictionary key plus the new item. But now, I want to assign for each key of the new dictionary a value of a list.

So, I wrote this code:

```py
   old_dict={22:[99,4['Dog','Dog.1']],14:[99,8['Dog2','Dog.3']],23:[97,8['Cat2','Dog.3']]}
   new_dict={22|14:[99,4['Dog','Dog.1']],14|25:[99,8['Dog2','Dog.3']],23|5:[97,8['Cat2','Dog.3']]}
   list=[[99,4['Dog','Dog.1']],[99,8['Dog2','Dog.3']],[97,8['Cat2','Dog.3']]]
    new_dict2 = {}
    for values in list:
        for old, new in zip(old_dictionary.keys(), new_dictionary.values()):
            new_ID = old + '|' + new
            new_dict2[new_ID] = values
```

However, this is repeating the first value of the list, in all the keys of the new dictionary.

Please, how do I correct this error?

Comment: Did you want to `zip` the values from `list`, too, i.e. `for old, new, values in zip(final_dict.keys(), final_results_2.values(), list):`?

Comment: No, do you this I should?

Comment: Sofia, could you please provide example with data of the list, old dict and new dict with desirable behavior?

Comment: @kirillFedyanin I edited the question to provide an example of the dictionary and list.

Comment: Your example dicts and lists are not valid Python syntax.

Comment: The issue is things like `old_dict={1:22:3:` - not compatible with python `dict` syntax of `key:value,key:value`

Comment: @JimEisenberg I corrected the IDs of the dictionaries.

Comment: see `print( 22|14 )` - `22|14` is not the same as string `"22|14"`. Simply use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments - it helps to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my  problem this way:

```
    final_all={}
    for old_k,new_k in zip(old_dictionary.keys(),new_dictionary.keys()):
        new_ID=str(old_k) + '|' + str(new_k )
        final_all[new_ID]=list_values
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

22|14 is a bitwise OR function. You probably want your leys to be text. so keep them in quotes "22|14"

Your solution is to split keys and values and then recombine them. It should look like this:

```
keys1, values1 = dict1.items()
keys2, values2 = dict2.items()
new_keys = [str(a)+'|'+str(b) in zip (keys1, keys2)]
new_dict = {k:v for k, v in zip (new_keys, some_new values)}
```